# Can I avoid creating a local variable when finding a maximum or minimum property in an Array?

Tags: ruby

I have the following simple code:

```
max_length = 0
chains.each { |x| if x.resolution < min_resolution min_resolution = x.resolution }
chains.delete_if { |x| x.resolution > min_resolution }
```

where `chain`s have the property `resolution`, and I want to delete all `chain`s that don't have the lowest `resolution`. This solution works, but I'm trying to keep my code tidy and am trying to avoid local variables. Is there a way to solve the problem above without creating the variable `max_length`?

Comment: give us some sample inputs. and outputs too.

Comment: Your code looks invalid. What is `if` doing?

Comment: @sawa: it *is* invalid :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You are right. I tried to be too nice.

Comment: "I am trying to avoid local variables". Where did you get that advice? that's possibly the worst you can do. Using local variables (when necessary) with meaningful names, to store intermediate values of the computation is the first step to write good code (IMO the second would be make the data structures inmutable whenever possible). Here it makes complete sense to store that minimum value (doing a single looping is either space wasteful (`group_by`) or requires intrincate code. Not worth it. Also, any reason not to create a new chains array instead of doing an in-place update?

Comment: you're right!  I'm sorry about that.  And my question has now been appropriately edited.  Though the code is still invalid.  Fortunately, the answers below are, while maybe not what I was hoping for, fantastic.

Comment: The answer from steenslag now is exactly what I was hoping for :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#sample data:
Chain = Struct.new(:resolution)
chains = 1000.times.map{Chain.new(rand(100))}

# do work:
p chains.group_by(&:resolution).min.last
#=>[#<struct Chain resolution=0>, #<struct Chain resolution=0>, ...]
```

Comment: Now that's the oneliner we've been waiting for :)

Comment: I didn't know `Hash#min`. This is new to me.

Comment: @sawa: Hash is an Enumerable. It gets it for free.

Comment: I see. So it is sorted by the key, then by the value of the hash.

Comment: @sawa: Yes, but since it's illegal to have two keys that are equal to one another, it effectively just sorts by key.

Answer (score 5):

From the top of my head I don't see a way without precalculating minimal value before deletion. But you can prettify the code. What about this?

```
min_res = chains.map(&:resolution).min
chains.delete_if {|c| c.resolution > min_res }
```

Comment: I wanted to upvote both Sergio's and Dogbert's answers, but since Dogbert's is deleted, it goes to Sergio.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I get the question correctly. Under the interpretation that you do not have or need duplicates, I think this is enough:

```
[chains.min_by(&:resolution)]
```

Comment: no this is not enough! As `OP` doesn't give any input you can't use `min_by` this way.

Comment: @sawa: this will select only one element with lowest resolution, right? But there may be multiple.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `a = [[1,2],[3,1]] ; a.min_by(&:last)` Now how would you use this for your next `delete_if`? So how that's correct?

Comment: `.min_by` will only return one element.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, Dogbert You are right. I realized that after I posted it. But that is my interpretation.

Comment: @sawa as you realized,either edit to correct one or delete post. based on the guess don't post any answers. It is very bad.

Comment: @Priti what's wrong with making assumptions (if you state them)?

Comment: @JanDvorak assumption should be in the comment,not in the answers.

Comment: @Priti: I don't mean to be rude, but seems that sawa should know more about the dos and the donts than you do.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ohh! really ? so what made you think so?

Comment: @Priti: his high rep, for one :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev In this way people are measured in SO? If so really very bad.

Comment: @Priti: you still have a lot to learn. Would you please stop backticking words that are not code?

Comment: @Priti: It's not the way "people are measured." It is not a measure of you or sawa as a person! But someone with a high reputation score has shown himself to be pretty well acquainted with the "dos and don'ts" of Stack Overflow in order to get that score, so it's not an unreasonable statement. Also, only returning one result is also an assumption — given an incomplete problem description, every answer will make assumptions, so that is an unreasonable criticism IMO.